# Speeding up TSQL

Tags: t-sql, optimization

Hi all i wondering if there's a more efficient way of executing this TSQl script. It basically goes and gets the very latest activity ordering by account name and then join this to the accounts table. So you get the very latest activity for a account. The problem is there are currently about 22,000 latest activities, so obviously it has to go through alot of data, just wondering if theres a more efficient way of doing what i'm doing?

```
DECLARE @pastAppointments TABLE (objectid NVARCHAR(100), account NVARCHAR(500), startdate DATETIME, tasktype NVARCHAR(100), ownerid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, owneridname NVARCHAR(100), RN NVARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @pastAppointments (objectid, account, startdate, tasktype, ownerid, owneridname, RN)
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT fap.regardingobjectid, fap.regardingobjectidname, fap.actualend, fap.activitytypecodename, fap.ownerid, fap.owneridname,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fap.regardingobjectidname ORDER BY fap.actualend DESC) AS RN 
    FROM FilteredActivityPointer fap
    WHERE fap.actualend < getdate() 
    AND fap.activitytypecode NOT LIKE 4201 
) tmp WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY regardingobjectidname

SELECT fa.name, fa.owneridname, fa.new_technicalaccountmanagername, fa.new_customerid, fa.new_riskstatusname, fa.new_numberofopencases,
fa.new_numberofurgentopencases, app.startdate, app.tasktype, app.ownerid, app.owneridname
FROM FilteredAccount fa LEFT JOIN @pastAppointments app on fa.accountid = app.objectid and fa.ownerid = app.ownerid
WHERE fa.statecodename = 'Active' 
AND fa.ownerid LIKE @owner_search 
ORDER BY fa.name
```

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you on?

Comment: SQl Server 2005 (unfortunately!)

Comment: The other thing that might be useful, is this is being run using SSRS, to create a report. Not sure if using the inbuilt sorting functions in ssrs is quicker than using order by in tsql?

Comment: Does objectid  is numeric and could be an INT type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove `ORDER BY regardingobjectidname` from the first `INSERT` query - the only (narrow) purpose such a sort would have on an `INSERT` query is if there was an identity column on the table being inserted into. And there isn't in this case, so if the optimizer isn't smart enough, it'll perform a pointless sort.